# can not run the matrix operation C program in code blocks

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, codeblocks

I've written a C code for matrix operation. The rows and columns values should be user defined. When I try to run the code, a pop up appears displaying "`matrix_addition.exe has stopped working`". Why is it so? While building the code there is no error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int r,c,i,j,a_matrix[r][c],b_matrix[r][c];
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &r, &c);

    printf("enter the elements of the first matrix \n");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("a_matrix[%d][%d]:",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&a_matrix[i][j]);  //array input
        }
    }

    printf("\n enter the elements of the second matrix \n");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("b_matrix[%d][%d]:",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&b_matrix[i][j]);  //array input
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please see the image attached of the error popup.
[image]

Comment: Did you expect `a_matrix` and `b_matrix` to magically grow to the proper size once `r` and `c` were assigned valid values? That's not how C works, in general.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) variable names should indicate `content` or `usage`  (or better, both).

Comment: the values of the variable `r` and `c` must be assigned before using them to declare the arrays: `a_matrix[r][c]` and `b_matrix[r][c]`  <-- this is the main problem with the code

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program makes use of variable length arrays. But it initialized them with variables that have unspecified values. The behavior of your program is undefined, and you are lucky it crashed instead of appearing to work.

```
int r,c,i,j,a_matrix[r][c],b_matrix[r][c];
    ^
    unspecified value used to initialize the sizes of a_matrix and b_matrix
```

The immediate solution is to simply move the matrix definitions after you got user input:

```
int r,c,i,j;
printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix\n");
scanf("%d %d", &r, &c);

int a_matrix[r][c], b_matrix[r][c];
```

VLA's were introduced by C99, and another feature introduced with that standard is the ability to define variables anywhere in a block scope, not just the beginning. In fact, you should strive to define variables as close to their initial point of use, as possible. IMO that makes code much clearer to read than having them all bunched up together in the beginning of a function.

---

I'd be remiss if I did not warn you the using VLA's runs a certain risk. Most modern implementations of the C language use a call stack that contains a functions variables during run-time. That call stack is fairly limited in size, and if you define a very big VLA on it, your program will overflow the stack and terminate immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You invoke *undefined behaviour* as you define two variable length arrays but initialize them with variables ***you have not yet taken as input***, thus ***their values are not specified***.

You can move the declaration of your arrays exactly after the point where you read their size. So change this part :

```
int r,c,i,j,a_matrix[r][c],b_matrix[r][c];
printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix\n");
scanf("%d %d", &r, &c);
```

to :

```
int r,c,i,j;
printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix\n");
scanf("%d %d", &r, &c);
int a_matrix[r][c], b_matrix[r][c];
```